# How to push and pull modified docker's images automatically?

Tags: git, docker

I have a docker image that I can run in many servers with different parameters.
Into the docker image, there is a git repository that needs to be pulled any how.
So I need something that:

1. run the "master" image of the docker in interactive mode (-it)
2. pull the git repository inside the docker
3. commit the container's differences (caused by the git pull)
4. push the new image to a docker cloud registry
5. pull the new image in each server where the docker was already been installed

some questions:

- is this procedure correct or there are other ways?
- is there any way to do steps 1,2 passing some arguments to the `run` command, like a bash script or something else?
- when I do `docker pull <new image>`, do I need to turn the already running docker's container off and restart it after the pull operation ends or docker is so smart to understand that it needs to restart the container?
- I found [watchtower](https://github.com/v2tec/watchtower) that can handle the container's update, also remotely. I didn't try it yet, but I will.

  EDIT:
  I have created 2 scripts. The first inside the docker image that performs the git pull. The second outside the docker image that will be started from a user or an automatic program. This second script does:
- run the docker into detached mode, getting the container id that returns from the run command
- exec the first script using the `docker exec` command
- commit the container using the previous saved container id
- push the new image into the cloud registry
- stop the container

Now I need to try the `watchtower` program or find another tools.

Comment: Just a thought, did you look into: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint ? You could make a script that when the container runs will perform the git pull and get the latest version of the repo, this way the docker image would always be the same and you would only need another mechanism to force-recreate these containers

Comment: thanks @Hito for the reply. Actually yes I found the entrypoint command script but I don't want that each time I start the docker it will performs the git pull. I want to centralize the managing of each docker image all over my servers and that each image will be the exact copy of the master image. Also, if I will have docker that never stops I cannot trigger the entrypoint. I found another solution for the moment, I will write down in the EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the net effect of this, you should:

1. Write a `Dockerfile` that does the work of installing your application in a pristine Docker container (running `docker build` will make an image out of it)
2. Check this `Dockerfile` into your git repository alongside your source code
3. Set up some CI system to rebuild the Docker container on every change and tag it with some unique tag (a timestamp, the git commit hash, a relevant git tag) and push it to a repository
4. On the systems where the containers are running, `docker stop && docker rm` them, then `docker run` them with the new tagged image

This approach has two important advantages over what you describe.  The first is that anybody who has the source repository can rebuild exactly the running image.  (In your approach if you accidentally lose a running container you can't reproduce what was running.)  The second is that, if a build goes wrong, it's easy enough to roll back to running the previous version of the image just by changing the tag back.

In particular, if you're asking "can I run something like a bash script, with `docker run`, so that I can `docker commit` the result", a `Dockerfile` is almost exactly what you're looking for.

The last step is the least well-defined of these.  You can use a simple cluster manager tool like Ansible to cause containers to be running in places; or update an image version in something like a Docker Compose YAML file running on Docker Swarm; or the watchtower tool you identified it looks like could do it.  This is something that Kubernetes does extremely well, but it's...an investment.

In the workflow you describe, there are a couple of things I would say are distinctly not best practices in production environments.  I'd suggest you should basically never use `docker commit` (`docker build` is quite straightforward and gives you reproducible image builds; even in the context of an SO question "here's my Dockerfile" is much easier to describe than "I did a bunch of stuff in a container and then committed it").  `docker exec` is useful for debugging but shouldn't be the principal way you interact with containers.  Finally, using the same image name/tag and committing different images under that same tag makes it difficult to roll back to an older version of the code ("don't use the `:latest` tag").

Comment: Thank you very much for your extremely satisfying reply!
I'm basically new in the Docker world so I'm trying to understand it.
I have created a Dockerfile that takes about 10/15 minutes to be compiled, is it common building time or it is extreamly too time to wait? this is the main
reason that discourages me to rebuild each time the Dockerfile. I have to say that the only reason I need to rebuild it is because the git repository inside the
docker image has been modified, so I need to update it and propagate the new version to the other servers.

Comment: That's unusual.  If the repository that includes the `Dockerfile` is very very large then there's an initial copy step that can take a lot of time; excluding files via a `.dockerignore` file can help.  If there are first-time setup steps that take a while then `docker build` will remember the second time you run it the result of the first run and essentially skip them.  On more modest projects (especially if there's not a "compile" step involved) building an image generally takes me seconds.

Comment: in this case I have a bunch of apt packets to install and some preliminary web call operation to do.
I have followed a lot of "how to make a Dockerfile" and "Dockerfile Best Practise" and I have tried to apply all
those countermeasure to keep the image size low but the result is a 1.5GB image.
In particular I have >30 apt packets to install, 2 git repo to clone and other few web calls to make.